# ProcessBuilder - Start another process / JVM - HowTo?

Tags: java, testing, process, jvm, fork

I'm writing a network app, where each Client has a Singleton ClientManager.
For *testing*, I would like to create several clients (each in their own VM / process) without starting the program by hand n-times.

The following two questions on stackoverflow already describe how-to do that:

- [Is *this* really the best way to start a second JVM from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229605/is-this-really-the-best-way-to-start-a-second-jvm-from-java-code)
- [Java: Executing a Java application in a separate process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636367/java-executing-a-java-application-in-a-separate-process/723914#723914)

My Code is based on these, but it's not working:

- The main program doesn't continue after spawn is called.
- The spawned code doesn't get executed.

Here's the complete code using [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

```
public class NewVM {
  static class HelloWorld2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Hello World");
      System.err.println("Hello World 2");
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    startSecondJVM(HelloWorld2.class, true);
    startSecondJVM(HelloWorld2.class, false);
    System.out.println("Main");
  }
  public static void startSecondJVM(Class<? extends Object> clazz, boolean redirectStream) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(clazz.getCanonicalName());
    String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
    String path = System.getProperty("java.home")
            + separator + "bin" + separator + "java";
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = 
            new ProcessBuilder(path, "-cp", 
            classpath, 
            clazz.getCanonicalName());
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(redirectStream);
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    process.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Fin");
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong???

Btw:

- I'm using Eclipse.
- The Singleton problem is a *simplified* example. Please do *not* suggest creating a factory.

**Solution:** HelloWorld2 mustn't be an inner class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you make HelloWorld2 a top level class.  It appears java expects a top level class.

This is the code I tried.

```
class Main
{
    static class Main2
    {
        public static void main ( String [ ] args )
        {
            System . out . println ( "YES!!!!!!!!!!!" ) ;
        }
    }

    public static void main ( String [ ] args )
    {
        System . out . println ( Main2 . class . getCanonicalName ( ) ) ;
        System . out . println ( Main2 . class . getName ( ) ) ;
    }
}

class Main3
{
    public static void main ( String [ ] args )
    {
        System . out . println ( "YES!!!!!!!!!!!" ) ;
    }
}
```

1. *getCanonicalName* and *getName* return different names.  Which one is right? They are both wrong.
2. Main3 works.

Answer (score 2):

I think I see a fix for part of the problem: `process.waitFor()` prevents control from returning to main() before the subprocess ends.

To figure out why your spawned process isn't starting, I'd recommend printing out all the arguments to the `ProcessBuilder` constructor and checking that a hand-called JVM called with those arguments succeeds. In particular, you need that class name to be the name of a class having a `static void main(String[])`.