# Execute Java main method from within a Java desktop app in a different JVM

Tags: java, jvm

I have a desktop app and when someone presses a button I want it to kick off another JVM that executes a class' main method.  My desktop app already depends on the jar that contains the class with the main method that I want to execute.

Currently I've got the following code, however, I was hoping their was a more elegant way of doing this:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec("java -jar another.jar");
```

I know I can use ProcessBuilder too.

Is there no way such as (excuse the pseudo code):

```
Jvm.execute(Main.class);
```

Since the Main class that I want to call already exists in my classpath, it just feels weird to have to run the `java` command via Runtime.

Comment: And you cannot execute that main method from your code?

Comment: Is starting new background thread acceptable for you? In that case you could even report task finishing to user.

Comment: A different jvm is what I want.

Comment: There's no built-in method for starting another JVM.  That's the basic code you need, though there are tweaks you can make.  See [Is *this* really the best way to start a second JVM from Java code?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229605/is-this-really-the-best-way-to-start-a-second-jvm-from-java-code) for details.

Comment: I believe there is no way to do it like you suggested.

Comment: Then instead of using main method it's possible to have other JVM running all the time and listening for some event using sockets.

Comment: Have you considered using ANT `exec` or `java` task ?? Have a look at http://ant.apache.org/manual/tasksoverview.html#exec ... in this way you just have to invoke an 'ant' task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very good question. Try to search into management API: http://cupi2.uniandes.edu.co/javadoc/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/package-frame.html

Good luck.

I am not sure that this API exists, but if it is it should be there.
I'd personally used ProcessBuilder as you but specify explicit path to java by retrieving system properties of current process.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to execute this Main class in another JVM? It only complicates things.

Usually just Main.main(args) will be OK, however:

If you want to isolate that program from your program, just run it under another classloader - see URLClassLoader documentation. Notice that even complex Java application servers don't create many processes (usually it's just one JVM process), and isolate deployed WARs and EARs with just classloaders. You may think of classloader as a JVM's equivalent of process.

If that another program does some 'insecure' operations, use Java's security mechanism from java.security and prevent that program from doing those operations.

If that another program calls System.exit() and this stops your program, it's enough to use the security mechanism, and forbid that program to call System.exit() - see System.exit() Javadoc. Then you can just catch SecurityException and ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

HSQLDB has a generic solution for invoking the main methods for multiple different processes. Use this class to invoke any process [MainInvoker class source](http://hsqldb.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/hsqldb/base-one/trunk/src/org/hsqldb/util/MainInvoker.java?revision=3921&view=markup)