# Is it too risky to call Thread.stop on a runaway GroovyShell server thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, groovy

I'd like to add [groovy-shell-server](https://github.com/bazhenov/groovy-shell-server) to our application.  We have run into a couple production issues recently where a call to an internal API could have expedited diagnosis or even provided a short-term fix.  Groovy-shell-server provides a nice way to achieve this.

But actually using this in production introduces a potential complication.  Let's say that, despite careful peer review, we execute a script which pegs the CPU, or gets stuck in an endless loop.  I need some way to kill that thread, pronto!  So I was thinking about enhancing groovy-shell-server to support an optional hard stop() of a running Groovy client thread.

I know that [Thread.stop() is inherently unsafe](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html); it's been [discussed on StackOverflow  before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283328/are-thread-stop-and-friends-ever-safe-in-java).  My question is, do you think the benefits might outweigh the risks in this case?  Is using Thread.stop() a pragmatic choice as a kind of "emergency brake" for a runaway GroovyShell server thread?  Or the likelihood of leaving objects in an inconsistent state is too high?

*(Alternately, if someone has a better way to provide programmatic, **interruptible** access to a running java application, I'm all ears.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that generally is it bad to use deprecated API and specifically it is not recommended to use `Thread.stop()`.

BUT there is not rule without exception. I think this is the case. According to my experience `Thread.stop()` works and really stops thread. I used it many years ago in applet that was targeted for Netscape. Some of its versions did not support `Thread.interrupt()` well.

The only alternative solution I can think about is using separate process. But in this case you have to implement some process-to-process transport for data transfer. I do not know details of your task but usually the price is too high.

So, if I were you I'd use `Thread.stop()` with very big apologize comment.

Comment: I'm not actually not disputing whether or not Thread.stop() will really stop the thread - it definitely will.  The question is whether it is too *risky* to stop the thread due to the potential of leaving various objects in a bad state.  In general though I think I agree with you that this is probably one case where the benefits outweight the risks.

Comment: @greghmerrill *Thread.stop() will really stop the thread - it definitely will.*, not necessarily threads waiting on a monitor may not be stopped (i.e. you have to kill the thread the holds the lock 1st). `Thread.stop()` is *almost* ok in case you know if you can use it, examine the stack trace and mark some dangerous moments. Alternatively use a code enhancer that peppers the code and checks `Thread.interrupt()` or calls any other static *safe point* to throw an error similar to ThreadDeath.

Comment: @bestsss _not necessarily threads waiting on a monitor may not be stopped (i.e. you have to kill the thread the holds the lock 1st)_ - this was news to me, thanks for the tip!  I [tried it out](https://gist.github.com/1183567) and you are definitely right, stopping a Thread which is acquiring a lock will _not_ immediately stop that thread, although it will stop as soon as the lock is acquired.

Comment: Going with this response as that's how I intend to proceed, i.e. by using Thread.stop() with judicious comments & caveats.

Comment: @greghmerrill, you're welcome. What i usually do is stopping entire ThreadGroups (not by ThreadGroup.stop(), though). There are dangerous areas that if the stack trace shows about you should skip and re-try stop after a few nanos. (for instance `java.util.concurrent.locks`). Other option would be to change groovy itself to add some code that often checks Thread.interrupt(), it should be a relatively easy to implement. Note 2: stopping (throwing ThreadDeath) occurs at HotSpot safe points and it's virtually impossible to know where a SP will be placed.