# java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException in ExecutorCompletionService

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I am getting java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException when I use ExecutorCompletionService to submit threads

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" 
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:127)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1239
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:431)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:406)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:917)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Code snippet

```
CompletionService<Object> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<Object>(executor);
List<Future<Object>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Object>>();
for (ThreadClass mt : threadList) {
    futures.add(completionService.submit(mt));
}

while (futures.size() > 0) {
    Future<Object> f = completionService.take();
    futures.remove(f);
    try {
        Object result = f.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      //fetches threadlist here
        killThread(threadList);
    }
}
```

And again in its child threads , list of threads are created and the actual processing is down in that thread.

Update:
I have noticed that the above exception does not comes if I comment killThread(threadList);

```
public void killThread(ArrayList<Long> threadIdList)
{
    for(long threadId : threadIdList)
    {
        Set<Thread> setOfThread = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
        for(Thread thread : setOfThread){
            if(thread.getId() == threadId){
                thread.stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know I should interrupt the thread of use executor.shutdownNow() but this both does not terminate all the threads.
As I cannot add interrupt handling in child as I don't want to execute child logic inside a loop.Its an one time long running activity.

Comment: Your variable names don't seem to match. Can you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: Show us the code of ThreadClass

Comment: If that's actually from your code, the problem is likely confusion between `completionService`, `ompletionService`, and `w_completionService`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo..I have updaated my question

Comment: Why do you `killThread()`, if there's an Exception, the Thread is terminated anyway. You should never fiddle with Threads you don't create yourself.

Comment: @GuillaumeF...If there is an exception in any of the child threads ,I want to kill all other threads as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882241/why-thread-stop-method-isnt-safe-to-use

Comment: Re, "If there is an exception in any of the child threads, I want to kill all other threads as well."  Don't ever kill a thread.  Ask it to stop.  Threads should always _cooperate_ with one another.

Comment: Seems you are using lock utilities but we can't see that in your code, looking at the exception it seems you are trying to released lock which was not acquired.