# Thread End Determination

Tags: java, multithreading

The following thread runs on a button click.

```
open.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        calls();
    }
});


private void calls() {
    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    reads();
}

public void reads() {
    ....
    ....
    counter++;
    // The Thread should stop here right>
}
```

But it doesn't end there. I am using `thread.stop()` to stop the thread there. I know the range the counter has to go. I display counter value in UI. If I click the open button once the counter reaches the end state, then it shows an `Interrupted` exception.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283328/are-thread-stop-and-friends-ever-safe-in-java

Comment: This threads are action performed on the main thread.

Comment: I don't know why there is a down vote here. I have seen the topic you have suggested. I posted the question here because I couldn't understand that. I know stop() method is deprecated but it is the only way my thread stops else it shows exception when I click open button again

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. If you have a `Thread.currentThread().stop()` in your method `reads()`, why did you remove it? That's the kind of thing you need to show. And where do you get this InterruptedException?

Comment: If I click the open button again I get InterruptedException. I don't know how but now it works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your `t` object outside the function, maybe in the constructor. Then you can stop it with this:

```
 t.interrupt();
```

**EDIT**

```
Thread t;
public myclass()//your constructor
{
t=new Thread(this);
}

    open.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            calls();
        }
    });


    private void calls() {
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        reads();
    }

    public void reads() {
        ....
        ....
        counter++;
t.interrupt();// The Thread should stop here right>

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it works fine now and I don't have any idea this works.

Comment: You're welcome. Use t.interrupt instead of t.stop when you want to stop your thread. Because it's not safe.

Comment: Why would you want to interrupt your own thread from within in its run method? reads() is called from run(). Origianl question : seems to be worked out some other way per Parthe comment but am sure interrupt did not help